# Dunn.test in R: are adjusted p-values corrected for number of comparisons?

Tags: r, nonparametric, dunn-test

I've performed a post-hoc Dunn's test with Sidak adjustment using the dunn.test code for R.  There are three groups in my comparison and I understand from the R help files that the lower number in the output is the adjusted p-value which I use to compare to alpha (0.05).

My question is: do I divide alpha by three (since I've three comparisons), or does the adjusted p-value generated by R factor in that I have three comparisons and I simply compare the value with alpha?

Thanks for any help (including pointing me to another discussion).  Have googled in vain.

[image]

EDIT: I first performed a Kruskal-Wallis test and a signficanct difference in the groupings was identified.  Also I am very new to R and have read to the best of my ability before posting (am not a statistician).  I do understand from the dunn.test manual that the output from holm adjustment and others mark rejection with a asterisk.  It is interpretation of the Sidak output I'm confused about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Author of `dunn.test` here. As per the help file for `dunn.test` under the `sidak` option for the `method` argument:

> the FWER is controlled using Šidák's (1967) adjustment, and adjusted p-values = max(1, 1 - (1 - p)^m).

So, **Yes. `dunn.test` corrects *p*-values for multiple comparisons given the argument to `method`.** For the Šidák option, you would reject each null hypothesis if $p\le \alpha/2$ (i.e. `dunn.test` report one-sided *p*-values).

Also from the help file:

> `method` adjusts the *p*-value for multiple comparisons using the Bonferroni, Šidák, Holm, Holm-Šidák, Hochberg, Benjamini-Hochberg, or Benjamini-Yekutieli adjustment (see Details). The default is no adjustment for multiple comparisons.

For the stepwise multiple comparisons adjustment methods, because rejection depends *both* on adjusted *p*-values (sometimes called *q*-values) *and* the ordering of *unadjusted* *p*-values, rejection decisions for a specified level of $\alpha$ are starred in the output.

The advantage of not starring output for the static results is that adjusted *p*-values can be interpreted by the reader according to their own preference for $\alpha$.

Comment: thank you sincerley for your answer.  As I non-stats person I had tried to understand the method argument but was unable to interpret.  Your expertise is much appreciated.